# Stopping the use of Tab/Alt-F4 in a full-screen program in Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

I need a way to stop people using other programs while my Java program is running. i.e stopping people switch tabs and pressing Alt-F4.

Comment: I don't think you can do so without resorting to platform-dependent JNI. A good question.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? The whole point of running a multitasking operating system is so that people CAN do that.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the program full screen use;

```
 window.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //maximise window

 window.setUndecorated(true); //remove decorations e.g. x in top right
```

And to make the window always on top use(To stop people using other running programs);

```
window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Comment: Does a maximized window prevent access to the Window taskbar?  If your window is set to always be on top, will it obscure any modal dialogs you might put up later?

Comment: If the window loses focus the task bar does become visible but you can use a robot to click when the window loses focus as a fix :D

Answer (score 7):

You're not going to be able to do this at the Java level - you'll need to put the operating system into a "Kiosk Mode" of some kind.

Unsolicited commentary - Do you need this because you (or your customer) hate your users, and want them to curse you forever?  Are you planning to add features like "shut down the computer" to your program?

Comment: +1 for the unsolicited commentary.  I would quickly uninstall such a program.

Comment: Maybe it's a program for some kind of public terminal or something. I can hardly imagine why such a program would be necessary on a normal desktop PC or a laptop.

Answer (score 6):

If your looking for full screen support, this is the code I use. Should be enough to get you going. You just need a global boolean variable to say if the application is full screen or not. You can tinker with it to get it to display a you like.

```
 /**
     * Method allows changing whether this window is displayed in fullscreen or
     * windowed mode.
     * @param fullscreen true = change to fullscreen,
     *                   false = change to windowed
     */
    public void setFullscreen( boolean fullscreen )
    {
        //get a reference to the device.
        GraphicsDevice device  = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        DisplayMode dispMode = device.getDisplayMode();
        //save the old display mode before changing it.
        dispModeOld = device.getDisplayMode();

        if( this.fullscreen != fullscreen )
        { //are we actually changing modes.
            //change modes.
            this.fullscreen = fullscreen;
            // toggle fullscreen mode
            if( !fullscreen )
            {
                //change to windowed mode.
                //set the display mode back to the what it was when
                //the program was launched.
                device.setDisplayMode(dispModeOld);
                //hide the frame so we can change it.
                setVisible(false);
                //remove the frame from being displayable.
                dispose();
                //put the borders back on the frame.
                setUndecorated(false);
                //needed to unset this window as the fullscreen window.
                device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                //recenter window
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setResizable(true);

                //reset the display mode to what it was before
                //we changed it.
                setVisible(true);

            }
            else
            { //change to fullscreen.
                //hide everything
                setVisible(false);
                //remove the frame from being displayable.
                dispose();
                //remove borders around the frame
                setUndecorated(true);
                //make the window fullscreen.
                device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                //attempt to change the screen resolution.
                device.setDisplayMode(dispMode);
                setResizable(false);
                setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                //show the frame
                setVisible(true);
            }
            //make sure that the screen is refreshed.
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a really extensive way of making the application full screen. Most other guides just include 'device.setFullScreenWindow(this);' but this may leave unwanted edges. I would personally remove the 'setLocationRelativeTo(null);' line though as the window seems to remember its old location and will return to it.