# Remove the possibility of using Alt-F4 and Alt-TAB in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Full Screen Program (Swing) -Tab/ALT F4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462454/java-full-screen-program-swing-tab-alt-f4)

I've got a full screen frame running and I wish to emulate a Kiosk environment. To do this, I need to "catch" all occurrences of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> pressed on the keyboard at all times. Is this even possible? My pseudocode:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     //get the keystrokes
     //stop the closing or switching of the window/application  
}
```

I'm not sure if keyPressed and it's associates (keyReleased and keyTyped) are the right way to go because from what I've read, they only handle single keys/chars.

Comment: if you can disable windows key by some softwares (it's common), then it should be no problem to disable alt+f4/tab features

Comment: The duplicate was found as the first result from a Google Search on 'Java prevent alt f4'. Try searching before asking as the answer may already be out there.

Comment: The post referenced above does not answer my question and only seems to really touch on making the application full screen. Hence why I asked the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To stop Alt-F4:

```
yourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

To stop Alt-Tab, you can make something more aggressive.

```
public class AltTabStopper implements Runnable
{
     private boolean working = true;
     private JFrame frame;

     public AltTabStopper(JFrame frame)
     {
          this.frame = frame;
     }

     public void stop()
     {
          working = false;
     }

     public static AltTabStopper create(JFrame frame)
     {
         AltTabStopper stopper = new AltTabStopper(frame);
         new Thread(stopper, "Alt-Tab Stopper").start();
         return stopper;
     }

     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             Robot robot = new Robot();
             while (working)
             {
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                  frame.requestFocus();
                  try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception) {}
             }
         } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }
     }
}
```

Comment: Marvelous!! Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: That takes away all use of the Alt key though

Comment: @StefanReich: Hahahaha, never even thought about it! Funny, people are still using this piece of code, 7 years after I wrote this.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux well, i am gonna use it on a April 1st prank, hope it still works good!