# Making JFrames the only object your allowed to focus on

Tags: java, locking, jframe, freeze

I would like to make a program that has a window pop up so that you were only allowed to interact with that window and no other part of your computer.  Kind of like when you have a security warning pop up forcing you to close that before you can continue normal operations with your computer.

Comment: You'll want to do a Google search on running a Swing application in *kiosk* mode. I believe that this will require some native code that is integrated with  your application via JNA or JNI. I do hope that you're not thinking of having users run this on their home machines but rather on a dedicated kiosk machine. Else you may have some very upset users.

Comment: This will be more of a home project of mine for my personal computer so shouldnt have to worry about any anger.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also look to making your application full screen, and take a look at the answer to this question[remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui)