# I need to stop certain key sequences from happening

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to stop certain key sequences from happening. I am building a `kiosk` type application for practice and whilst the app is running, I need to lock out the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combo's, and others like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui) but I tried to run it as a seperate class and incorporate it into my main class and I can still press <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Any and all help would be amazing!

Comment: Can you show where you're attempting to implement the solution that you linked to?

Comment: Some key combinations, for example Ctrl + Alt + Del, are really hard to intercept in any client program, and certainly in a platform-independent Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best if not only bet (without resulting to JNI) is to intercept KeyEvents using a KeyListener or KeyAdapter, and filter out those you want to block.
This MAY prevent these keystrokes from being intercepted by the operating system as well, but as Jesper indicates, it's far from certain whether this will actually happen.
To effectively intercept such things, you're going to have to install special software that sits much closer to the operating system, like customised keyboard drivers.

Comment: oh okay... so the url i provided, would that work for basic key combo blocking? And if so, where would i put the code?

Comment: it can serve as a basis, yes. Your job to figure out the specific codes to intercept. You'd probably need to have the listener running in every screen and popup of your system.

Comment: So would i apply it to the entire frame ? I only have one frame at the moment with multiple panels..

Comment: should work, I think. Been some 8 years since I've worked with Swing, so I'm rusty on the details.