# Disable Ctrl-alt-delete, alt-tab

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I am creating a LOGIN form that will automatically show up whenever the computer starts up.
I got it right though. My problem is, I have to disable the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> keystrokes when my program is already running. But the thing is, whenever I test my program, my computer gets lag. Especially when I include the method of disabling <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.
Somebody HELP!

```
public void altTab ()
{

try{

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            while(true){
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

                this.requestFocus(true);


            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get lag because of having an endless loop running again and again. Try putting an event on Key down and cancel it?(or release it)

Answer (score 1):

You cant disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> nor can you call it via your Robot class (using keypress or keyrelease - you can try it). And I don't think the code inside your while loop will run always- you are just releasing the key pressed. I am not sure about this, but you might try event handlers...

Answer (score 0):

Inside that loop, you should call Thread.sleep().  Take a look at this answer, which shares much of the same code you used:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6128105/2579661