# java - How do I prevent CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Tags: java, security

I'm currently working on a computer control software for my company, but whenever the program blanks the screen, the user can still press CTRL+ALT+DEL and then ESC and it frees the computer from control. I know this is possible, because in Faronics Insight, when you press CTRL+ALT+DEL, it doesn't do anything. The screen goes black for a second, but then Insight pops back up instead of the Windows Security Dialog. How does Insight bypass this security measure? How can I implement this into my own program? I can't even get it to detect the key sequence, because the OS steals the keyboard interrupt before it gets to my application. Would it be possible to check for a certain process like Windows Security or whatever and use a java.awt.robot to press escape? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui

Comment: You could try one of the solutions from here. Although, this is through the shell and not through a java app: http://superuser.com/questions/142176/how-can-i-disable-the-ctrl-alt-del-key-combination-completely-on-xp-vista-7

Comment: @BalwinderSingh `ALT-F4` is fundamentally different from `CTRL-ALT-DEL`

Comment: Here are some other means as well like disabling via the registry (using visual basic but you should be able to apply the same principle).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7392/Lock-Windows-Desktop

Though this isn't a good approach you are actively trying to do something Windows is trying to dissuade you from doing