# how to disable system keyboard handling in Java AWT Application?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, awt, keylistener

How can i disable such keys and their combinations as, for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> ; <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> and others in my Java AWT application?

E.g. my `KeyboardListener` should handle that keys as 'usual' keys and combinations without closing window or entering window menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this solution:

- for <kbd>Tab</kbd> - use `Frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);`
- for <kbd>Alt</kbd> - add `keyEvent.consume();` at the end of each key
  event handling code block

Then, to find out if <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed - use `keyEvent.isAltDown()` and `keyEvent.isControlDown()` methods of `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` events.

Thanks, @Hovercraft , for your quick response!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a program in "kiosk mode", something that requires more than Java to achieve (such as JNA or JNI). If you google this or search this site for this, you'll find out more about it. If I were using your code, though, I'd be very frustrated and perhaps angry, unless this were being run on a dedicated kiosk terminal.

Edit: Another option is as per this thread: [java-full-screen-program-swing-tab-alt-f4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462454/java-full-screen-program-swing-tab-alt-f4):

```
 window.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //maximise window
 window.setUndecorated(true); //remove decorations e.g. x in top right
 window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Edit 2: and this brute-force method: [Remove the possibility of using Alt-F4 and Alt-TAB in Java GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, the second link seems to be the most useful for me (developing remote control software) but if i would "release" the `Alt` key all the time, how do i hook it with `KeyboardListener` ?