# How to make my Java JFrame including panel fullscreen

Tags: java, swing

I am using Netbeans to do some Java and I want to make my application and it's frames full screen. The thing is, it goes fullscreen but then, since my frame is not as big it does not fill up the screen, [check image](http://s24.postimg.org/5mwiq0krn/FULL_IMAGE_TESSSS.png) if you don't understand. It has to like make the panel the user's resolution and put it in the center.

My code is as follow

```
public class frmMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public frmMenu() {
        initComponents();
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        this.setUndecorated(true);
    }
```

Comment: Heads-up, you should import JFrame instead of referencing it like that.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the easiest in Java. There's a lot of nuances to handle. Check this out: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4462524/489041)

This will call:

```
GraphicsDevice device  = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
```

Which can hook into the underlying operating system for full screen support rather than just making a big window.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29)

Answer (score 1):

Just to use toolkit to get screen size:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize()

```
int width = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
int height = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
setSize(width,height);
setUndecorated(true);
```

better way:

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = (int)dim.getWidth();
int height = (int)dim.getHeight();
setSize(width,height);
setUndecorated(true);
```

EDIT:
For good position set:

```
setLocation(0,0);
```

And i guess it is an image on the frame, you should scale it.
It will appear in upper left corner after setting the location.
I don't know how you render the image, to solve this you provide more source code.
For create graphics I advice to use something better than MS paint ;)

EDIT (2):
Rewrite:

```
getContentPane().add(panMenu);
```

To:

```
getContentPane().add(panMenu,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And remove line:

```
panMenu.setBounds(0, -20, 580, 630);
```

And make sure you have:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

for frame
Layouting with graphics interfaces are bad in absolute positioning. So maybe it won't correct it exactly because of absolute positioning in sub-panel

Comment: This is what happens, http://postimg.org/image/6zpsj9tgt/

Comment: @Jack my answer was edited

Comment: I see. But still, even if I would position it correctly, my pannel is still like not getting bigger nor is centered. It's like it was before. Image with added code of setLocation : http://postimg.org/image/evrhoyic9/

Comment: I don't know, how you render the image. Are you using drawImage method from Graphics? or some class from swing package? I need a piece of code with rendering to help you @Jack

Comment: Well I'm in Netbeans and I know I use Swing containers, so it must be Swing framework.

Comment: @Jack this is a layout issue. You should google for "How to use LayoutManagers in java"

Comment: I am not sure if it is a layout issue, surely it can be, agree with @ControlAltDel, but I dont know what it will do with the image, it will get scaled in strange way, you should center the image in the layout and rest of the frame fill with black color or something

Comment: @Maskacovnik and ControlAltDel Quick note, it's not an image. It's a panel with labels. But by layout, you mean like what exactly? I have learned mostly doing the layout by graphical interface and not much in code.

Comment: It seems you have a small panel in large frame, the panel seem to have fixed size, but I can't be sure without the source code. I advice you to use BorderLayout with center property to panel, it will scale the panel automatically (I never worked with graphical interface for layouts, but something like BorderLayout it should contain)

Comment: @maskacovnik Yep, it's a panel in a big frame, here is the code of the panel. 
`panMenu = new javax.swing.JPanel();

panMenu.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

panMenu.setLayout(null);

// Code of sub-components and layout - not shown here

getContentPane().add(panMenu);
panMenu.setBounds(0, -20, 580, 630);`

Comment: I have to response to my answer, there it will look terrible, see Edit(2), and I have to appologize to @ControlAltDel, he was right

Comment: @maskacovnik Quick upate. The thing is that my layout option was set the Null. Now it's free design so I can edit code. Current code of my layout is thhis. http://i.imgur.com/qubPgZU.png